# Change language for one user on Fedora 34 w/ XFCE

Tags: fedora, xfce, locale

I'm in a situation where I have to set the language for one user on Fedora 34 (with XFCE).

I found the settings to set the system language, but I can't figure out how to change the language for a user. The language locale in question is already installed (`pl_PL.utf8`), and I've set `LANG=pl_PL.utf8` in `~/.config/locale.conf`, but XFCE is still in english.

I read somewhere, that I should be able to select the locale while logging in, but it doesn't seem to work in Fedora. I'm not given the option to select a locale.

I cannot find it anywhere in the settings manager or in one of the hidden files in the user's home directory.

Just for clarification: I *don't* mean the system wide language! That one is quite easy to find, I mean the language for this one user, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora doesn't use this file.

You could edit your user `~/.bash_profile` file and add this:

`export LANG=pl_PL.utf8`

Or use: `~/.config/environment.d/` ([docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html)) - check `man environment.d`.

Gnome and KDE have built-in Control Centers to configure locale settings, other smaller DEs and window managers unfortunately need to be configured this way. It's sad there are no GUI tools to configure any DE in a unified way.

Comment: Based on your report I've gone ahead and filed a bug report because I didn't know the situation is so horrible. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1959036

Comment: `~/.bash_profile`? shouldn't it be just `~/.profile` if anything? I'm not starting XFCE from the bash, I'm just using the login manager

Comment: I was asking out of interest... No need to be rude.

Comment: Fedora developers admit that the situation is not perfect: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/19580

Comment: Added the link to the docs.